# HTML is not getting rendered on WEBGRID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

Webgrid is not rendering html, which is coming from sql for me. Please see my question below. Please help me as i am stuck in middle of it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.ReportName AS [Report Name] ,r.ReportDesc AS [Report Desc]
,<a href="user/details/12" class="aPopup">View Extra details</a> AS [Report Extra   
Details] FROM r.Reports and basically i am displaying this data directly on Webgrid.

The webgrid is dynamic and i am not specifying any columns name on it.

When i render my webgrid it shows the data as <a href="user/details/12"     
class="aPopup">View Extra details</a> in the column, instead i want to display it 
like "View Extra Details" with the hyperlink / link. Please help me how can i do this ?

Once it display the column with "View Extra details" i can have a jquery to open the     
popup, but the deal here how can i avoid displaying <a href="user/details/12"    
class="aPopup">View Extra details</a> in the column.

Looks like its not rendering the html on Webgrid, i tried Html.Raw but it was of no use.

Please let me know how to solve this issue.
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in eachFlowRow)
        {
            if (keyValuePair.Key.Contains("Report Extra Details"))
            {
                var newEntry = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(keyValuePair.Key, @Html.Raw("<a href='Home/Index' class='aPopup'>Vijay</a>"));
                row.Add(newEntry);
            }
            else
            {
                row.Add(keyValuePair);
            }
        }
```